# importing Couchnode as ESM gives error "[ERROR]: JSDoc '@augments' is not attached to a class."

Tags: node.js, couchbase, jspm, deno, es6-modules

I have a project i'm building in Deno and I'm trying to import the [couchbase nodejs client](https://github.com/couchbase/couchnode) via `https://dev.jspm.io/couchbase` but i'm getting an error:

> [ERROR]: JSDoc '@augments' is not attached to a class.

This happens during compile time. Any pointers are welcome.